# How to Integrate Apache Storm with Solace Message queue to receive messages from Solace .. just like spark streaming integration

Tags: integration, apache-storm, spark-streaming, solace, custom-receiver

I want to receive messages from [Solace](http://www.solacesystems.com/) queues and want to store in any data stores like Hbase/HDFS via Apache Storm.

Solace has published [integration guide](http://dev.solacesystems.com/integration-guides/spark-streaming/) to setup a custom receiver which will store the messages in Spark in-memory.
Other [integration guides](http://dev.solacesystems.com/docs/integration-guides/) were also available, except integration with Apache Storm.

I am not sure if this is possible or not. if this is, 
Can anyone give some pointers on the same(if not solace some other messaging provider) if they have already done this?

Comment: Why via Storm? Flume can do what you want to write to Hbase / HDFS

Comment: Earlier solution we had using Flume. with Hbase - AsyncHbaseSink which was working fine. I know that it can be achieved with Flume.  We also tried with Spark Streaming with solace, its working fine. This question is specific to Storm to test whether its working or not. This we are trying for better tools and techniques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Apache Storm's documentation, there's two ways to go about this.

1. Integrate via MQTT - https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/storm-mqtt.html
2. Integrate via JMS - https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-jms

   The storm-jms project provides a `SpringJmsProvider` where you can make use of the Spring framework (which Solace has a integration guide for) to lookup a `ConnectionFactory` and `Destination`.

   Alternatively, you can implement your own `org.apache.storm.jms.JmsProvider` to provide a `ConnectionFactory` and `Destination` without the Spring Framework.